# Query whith DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to get this result

expected result

```
CodeCompany      fechaActual    Clave  Usuario  Depto   entrada        salida       sumaHoras
2300                201712       307    USER1   TTT    06:00:04       14:04:12         8
```

This is my Query

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATETIME 
DECLARE @Hoy1 DATETIME 
DECLARE @Hoy2 DATETIME 

SELECT  @Hoy = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))
SELECT  @Hoy1 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'00:00:00'
SELECT  @Hoy2 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'23:59:59'



select c.CodeCompany,
       CONVERT(char(6), @Hoy, 112) AS fechaActual,
       a.idClave,
       c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
       d.Descripcion as Depto, 
       CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy1,108) fechaEntrada,
       CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy2,108) fechaSalida,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia
from   tblasistencia a 
JOIN   tblpersonal c 
ON     a.idClave = c.idClave
JOIN   tblDepto d 
ON     c.fkDepto = d.idDepto
where  fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @Hoy1,103) 
                    and CONVERT(DATETIME, @Hoy2,103)
and    fkStatus != 1
```

unexpected result

```
CodeCompany      fechaActual   Clave   Usuario   Depto     entrada      salida   sumaHoras

2300             201712        10120   USER1      TTT    00:00:00      23:59:59     8
```

The result is unexpected because not show the hour entry and exit time

Comment: there is no error here. CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'00:00:00' returns '2018-01-04 00:00:00.000'. So when you use CONVERT( .... , 108), it returns the 'time' part which is 00:00:00 you hard coded.

Comment: and how show the result expected?

Comment: where should the entrada 06:00:04 and salida 14:04:12 be coming from?

Comment: based on your query, your only getting the date from getdate() with hard coded '00:00:00' and '23:59:59'. your query cannot produce such 06:00:04 and 14:04:12 values.

Comment: the column entrada and salida come of tblAsistencia, but I defined the var Hoy1 and Hoy2 because the objetive of the Query is get the entry and exit time of the time current. But I don´t know how get the result true 06:00:04 and salida 14:04:12 with the time current

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy1,108) fechaEntrada,
 CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), @Hoy2,108) fechaSalida,
DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS horasAlDia
```

with

```
CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), Entrada,108) fechaEntrada,
 CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), Salida,108) fechaSalida,
DATEDIFF(HOUR, Entrada, Salida) %24 AS horasAlDia
```

Here is the script:

```
DECLARE @Hoy DATETIME 
DECLARE @Hoy1 DATETIME 
DECLARE @Hoy2 DATETIME 

SELECT  @Hoy = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))
SELECT  @Hoy1 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'00:00:00'
SELECT  @Hoy2 = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112))+'23:59:59'



 select c.CodeCompany,
 CONVERT(char(6), @Hoy, 112) AS fechaActual,
 a.idClave,
 c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
 d.Descripcion as Depto, 
 CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), Entrada, 108) fechaEntrada,
 CONVERT (VARCHAR(20), Salida, 108) fechaSalida,
 DATEDIFF(HOUR, Entrada, Salida) %24 AS horasAlDia
  from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
 JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
 where
   fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, @Hoy1,103) and 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, @Hoy2,103)and fkStatus !=1
```